# Does Hibernate OGM support Neo4j in Server Mode?

Tags: neo4j, hibernate-ogm

Through different examples on Hibernate OGM for Neo4j, i can find that Neo4j can be used only in Embedded mode.

If anyone has used Hibernate OGM with Neo4j in Server mode, please share the approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible yet. Atm. only the embedded mode is supported by Hibernate OGM.

Comment: is this feature planned some day for Hibernate OGM?

Comment: Yes, we'd love to add support for remote Neo4j servers (see [OGM-366](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-366)). Any help with that would be more than welcome. If you'd like to give it a short, let me know and we'll get you started.

Answer (score 1):

`Hibernate OGM 5.1.0.Alpha1` adds support for Neo4j in remote mode. The user can choose between the new Bolt protocol or the HTTP interface. See the [related blog](http://in.relation.to/2016/10/10/hibernate-ogm-5-1-alpha-and-5-0-2-released/) post for more details.